# neural network not training for long range

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I created a neural network in tensorflow. The networks is:

```
5 input variables a, b, c, d, e
y = sin(a)+ b + exp(c) - d*d + tanh(e)
50 neuron layer1, relu
20 neuron layer2, relu
10 neuron layer3, relu
1 neuron output layer
```

The nn easily converges (cost approx 0.0001) if input variables are in small range eg: -1 to 1 or -5 to 5. But if I increase the range it is not converging. The same network which converge for small input range, does not converge for big ranges. Why does this happen? How can I train for big range eg; -100 to 100 etc.

Comment: Could you post your entire code?

Answer (score 0):

Neural networks typically perform better on standardized or normalized inputs because their gradients behave better during backpropagation. This is for many reasons, but for example larger features will have a greater effect on the gradient, which is not necessarily what you want. For a deeper discussion you can see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7757/data-normalization-and-standardization-in-neural-networks) on CrossValidated.

One way to standardize your data is with [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Even easier is to add [Batch Normalization](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization) layer at your input, but this will slow down training a bit.